# How to install Ghost in a subdirectory with Nginx? (Getting 404)

Tags: nginx, ghost-blog

I'm a beginner using a reverse proxy or managing technical infrastructure. I have my main app (react + nginx) on a server and I'm trying to install Ghost on a subfolder https://tinymentions.io/blog on the same server as my main app.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to successfully configure Nginx to properly serve my Ghost blog.
When I visit the URL ttps://tinymentions.io/blog I get an error: "HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND"

I have searched the Ghost forum, Stack Overflow and all over Google, tried different approaches and unfortunately, I'm still not able to come up with a solution for this problem. Every time I tried a new approach, I restarted nginx with `sudo service nginx restart` but with no luck.

I would appreciate any help with this. If I'm not explaining myself correctly and/or need more information, please let me know.

**- What's your URL?**

My main app is on https://tinymentions.io/

**- Ghost URL**

https://tinymentions.io/blog

**- What version of Ghost are you using?**

Ghost-CLI version: 1.15.0
Ghost version: 3.35.5

**- What configuration?**

This is my NGINX config file:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name tinymentions.io www.tinymentions.io;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    root /var/www/tiny-mentions/build;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location /blog {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Update &http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:2368;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_connect_timeout 25000s;
      proxy_read_timeout 25000;

      if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
     }

     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
     }

     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
     }

      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/tinymentions.io/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/tinymentions.io/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = www.tinymentions.io) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = tinymentions.io) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name tinymentions.io www.tinymentions.io;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

}
```

The following is my config.production.json file:

```
{
  "url": "http://tinymentions.io/blog",
  "server": {
    "port": 2368,
    "host": "127.0.0.1"
  },
  "database": {
    "client": "mysql",
    "connection": {
      "host": "localhost",
      "user": "hidden",
      "password": "hidden",
      "database": "hidden"
    }
  },
  "mail": {
    "transport": "Direct"
  },
  "logging": {
    "transports": [
      "file",
      "stdout"
    ]
  },
  "process": "systemd",
  "paths": {
    "contentPath": "/var/www/ghost/content"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I was able to fix this issue.

It seems that nginx wasn’t restarting correctly so I had to stop nginx with the command `sudo systemctl stop nginx` and start it again using `sudo systemctl start nginx` to try different configurations and see if those finally worked.

The location /blog configuration on my NGINX config file that worked is the following:

```
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Update &http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:2368;
}
```

And the following is my config.production.json file that worked:

```
{
  "url": "https://tinymentions.io/blog",
  "server": {
    "port": 2368,
    "host": "127.0.0.1"
  },
  "database": {
    "client": "mysql",
    "connection": {
      "host": "localhost",
      "user": "hidden",
      "password": "hidden",
      "database": "hidden"
    }
  },
  "mail": {
    "transport": "Direct"
  },
  "logging": {
    "transports": [
      "file",
      "stdout"
    ]
  },
  "process": "systemd",
  "paths": {
    "contentPath": "hidden"
  }
}
```